# How Can I get the Training PipleLine from ITransformer of ML Model in ML.NET

Tags: asp.net-core, machine-learning, web, ml.net

```
ITransformer mlmodel = mlContext.Model.Load(path, out var inputschema);
```

this is my Saved model I want to change its inputshema but I want to retain the Trained Model.
I have tried

```
 mlmodel.Transform(trainingDataView);
```

"trainingDataView is my new Data But it Has not helped"
Tell me How can I get the training pipleline from Itransformer model that is been already trained model

Comment: Are you wanting to just retrain the model after loading it?

Comment: Yes I want to retain the trained model and just want to fit new data in this pipeline . actually the problem is I want to show data analysis for different products at a same page I want to use the same algorithm for all the products. So I want to get the data from database and want to fit the trained model. when I train it again it changes the result after every reload I don't want to retrain again just want to change the data

Comment: Not sure if you've seen but here's the doc to retrain a model - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/retrain-model-ml-net Note that only some algorithms are available to be retrained. Also note that the pipeline has to have the algorithm as the last item